# Constructing an invertible sheaf from a Cartier divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme. By definition, a Cartier divisor $D$ is a global section of the sheaf $\mathcal{M}_X^{\times}/\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}$, where $\mathcal{M}_X^{\times}$ is the sheaf of multiplicative units of the sheaf of rational functions. This in turn is equivalent to the data of a cover $\{ U_i\}$ of $X$ together with sections $f_i \in \mathcal{M}_X^{\times}$, that is, $f_i = g_i/h_i$ for nonzero divisors $g_i, h_i \in \mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$.

> I want to use this data to construct an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ from a Cartier divisor $D$.

This is part of an exercise that is proving to be too hard, so hints rather than answers would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're missing two conditions. One is that $g_i\in\mathcal{O}_X^\times(U_i)$ and the other is that $(f_i|_{ij})(f_j|_{ij})^{-1}\in\mathcal{O}_X(U_{ij})^{\times}$.

To construct a locally free sheaf from this simply define $\mathcal{L}|_{U_i}=\frac{1}{f_i}\cdot\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}\subseteq\mathcal{M}_X$. Then you need to check that there are isomorphisms $\phi_{ij}:(\mathcal{L}|_{i})|_{ij}\to(\mathcal{L}_j)|_{ij}$ such that $\phi_{ii}=id$ and $\phi_{jk}\circ\phi_{ij}=\phi_{ik}$.

Comment: @user347489 I'm not seeing why $g_i$ should be in $\mathcal{O}_X^\times(U_i)$. I do agree with the rest of your comment though.

Comment: @jgon because otherwise $f_i=g_i/h_i\not\in\mathcal{M}_X^\times$. But now I see that the OP wrote "nonzero", making my remark redundant.

Comment: @user347489 Ah yes, though I should point out that being in $\mathcal{O}_X^\times(U_i)$ is a much stronger condition than being nonzero (which is all that we need here). Hence my question, no worries.

Comment: @jgon you're right.